# MariaDB: Is there any way for every insert in local database should copy to remote database , apart from replication feature

Tags: sql, mariadb, copy

I have one table in host 1> DB1-> table1.

The table1 entries are getting created after every test run. I want to copy dynamically each newly created entry in local database to remote database.

Thanks,
Shell

I tried replication feature of mariaDB , but it copies all DBs and all tables from local to remote.
My need is just copy newly added entry on the spot at both DB without using replication feature.

I can create dump and import into another.
But how periodize it, it should run for each new entry without wait.

Comment: you can connect to another maraidb database and have access to its tables, so that a trigger can write automatically all new entries see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/federated-storage-engine/

Comment: But a simple python script, that runs on the server could alos establish a connection and grab the data

Comment: There is [replicate_do_table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-filters/) that does a single table.